# Execution of AsyncTask doInBackground is delayed

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a weird problem where I now look for ideas how to track it down.

The problem:
To address the performance, the app uses services, threads and AyncTasks. So far, so good. Everything worked as expected, but recently I introduced a regression.
I have a fragment that contains a Google Maps Fragment.
In the onStart-method of that fragment I create and start an AsyncTask that queries my content providers for the current data, storing it in private member variables for quick access upon redraws.

Now I have the problem that this async-task suddenly gets delayed and I don't know why.

AFAIK AsyncTasks use a threadpool and when this pool is exhausted, tasks get delayed. So I checked my code for AsyncTasks - especially long running ones. Added a bunch of log-messages, but no one of them seems to be running at that time.

Then I noticed that the delay only occurs when I have a service activated that monitors some directories for changes (using FileObservers). But in that service, I do not use any AsyncTasks or threads. There I create FileObservers for directories I am interested in and store those in a private list. That code is directly called from onStartCommand. So async tasks should not be affected by that.
Second, this only seems to happen in special circumstances. Mostly the updates are drawn immediately. Only if I start the app for the first time after an update from the Play Store or start it from Android-Studio, the delay occurs.
I can swipe it off the list of recent apps (which should kill the apps threads (but not process if the the services are running in that process)) and the updates continue to be queried in time (as long as that service was still running).
If I stop and then restart the service, I have that problem again.

The problem seems to be related to the start of this filewatcher-service.

So it seems that the start of this service blocks AsyncTasks for some time. ... but why?

Here an excerpt from the logfile from a first start of the app:
(I inserted some empty lines for readability)

```
02-05 22:00:54.361 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: onStart

02-05 22:00:54.672 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
02-05 22:00:54.679 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: onStartCommand: Start service (with intent)
02-05 22:00:54.700 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=92KB
02-05 22:00:54.702 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
02-05 22:00:54.702 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: After code cache collection, code=112KB, data=67KB
02-05 22:00:54.774 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: initWatchers
02-05 22:00:54.899 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: initWatchers1: Watcher for root /storage/emulated/0/Sync/BT-Shares/Leo intern created
02-05 22:00:54.973 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: initWatchers1: Watcher for subdirectory /storage/emulated/0/Sync/BT-Shares/Leo intern/Leo#GN created
02-05 22:00:55.047 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: initWatchers1: Watcher for subdirectory /storage/emulated/0/Sync/BT-Shares/Leo intern/Leo#N5x created
02-05 22:00:55.194 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: initWatchers finished
02-05 22:00:55.268 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: onStartCommand finished

02-05 22:00:55.350 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/SpeechHandler: startTextToSpeechService
02-05 22:00:55.515 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
02-05 22:00:55.557 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawContents (onMapReady)
02-05 22:00:55.800 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawContents: calculate bounds and move camera
02-05 22:00:55.891 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Choreographer: Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 22:00:56.040 24041-24211/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 6818200, Idb2b4cb785
                                                                      Build Date                       : 11/18/16
                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
                                                                      Local Branch                     : N25
                                                                      Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                      Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                      Reconstruct Branch               : 
02-05 22:00:56.047 24041-24211/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-05 22:00:56.047 24041-24211/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-05 22:00:56.248 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=101KB
02-05 22:00:56.249 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=99KB
02-05 22:00:56.249 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
02-05 22:00:56.367 24041-24199/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
02-05 22:00:56.379 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
02-05 22:00:56.380 24041-24199/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
02-05 22:00:56.380 24041-24199/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
02-05 22:00:56.404 24041-24253/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
02-05 22:00:56.553 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Compiler allocated 7MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
02-05 22:00:56.704 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
02-05 22:00:56.704 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
02-05 22:00:58.533 24041-24213/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: Leo#N5x was opened
02-05 22:00:58.577 24041-24213/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: Leo#N5x was closed (no write)
02-05 22:00:58.600 24041-24213/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: Leo#N5x was opened
02-05 22:00:58.695 24041-24213/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Receive_SharedFolderService: Leo#N5x was closed (no write)
02-05 22:00:59.522 24041-24048/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.092ms
02-05 22:01:00.344 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=241KB, data=221KB
02-05 22:01:00.345 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
02-05 22:01:00.346 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: After code cache collection, code=217KB, data=173KB
02-05 22:01:00.346 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
02-05 22:01:02.259 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=249KB, data=197KB
02-05 22:01:02.260 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: After code cache collection, code=247KB, data=197KB
02-05 22:01:02.260 24041-24045/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB

02-05 22:01:17.217 24041-24969/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: UpdateData.doInBackground (--start)
02-05 22:01:17.256 24041-24969/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/BuddyTrackerHelper: readBuddyPositions from 04.02.2017 22:01 to 17.08.292278994 08:12
02-05 22:01:17.518 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawContents (UpdateData.onPostExecute)
02-05 22:01:17.549 24041-24978/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
02-05 22:01:17.560 24041-24979/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
02-05 22:01:18.150 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawTrack: Track Leo#GN mit 77 Punkten eingetragen
02-05 22:01:18.601 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawTrack: Track Leo#N5x mit 239 Punkten eingetragen
02-05 22:01:18.618 24041-24041/de.leo.android.buddy_tracker I/Fragment_Map: drawContents: calculate bounds and move camera
```

The interesting parts:
At 22:00:54.361 the onStart Method of my map-fragment was entered. This method ends with a call to the AsyncTask to query my data.
In the background other tasks are running. One of them is the start of my filewatcher service at 22:00:54.679. This is finished at 22:00:55.268
Then the map became ready and a first attempt to draw data to the map is made at 22:00:55:557. No data available there - no problem!
At 22:00:58.533 the watched folders are accessed and the callbacks from the fileobservers are triggered.
Finally at 22:01:17.217 the AsyncTask from the onStart-method of the fragment is started.

So the question:
What causes this delay of 22s?
To repeat: This only happens if the filewatcher-service is active.

The onStart Method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
//noinspection ConstantConditions
if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "onStart");

super.onStart();

if (Application_Buddy_Tracker.getLocationProvider() != null)
    Application_Buddy_Tracker.getLocationProvider().registerClientIfLocationhandlerActive(this);

getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CONTENT_POSITIONS_URI, true, buddyPositionContentObserver);
new UpdateData().execute("--start");

LeoCommunication.collectGarbage(getActivity());

final SharedPreferences prefs = Application_Buddy_Tracker.getPreferences(getActivity());
setMapType(prefs);

//noinspection ConstantConditions
if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "onStart completed");
```

}

My Service:

```
public class Receive_SharedFolderService extends Service {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = Receive_SharedFolderService.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static @GlobalConstants.Debuglevels int DEBUG_LEVEL = DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE;


    public class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        String absolutePath;

        MyFileObserver(String path) {
            super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
            absolutePath = path;
        }


        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            if (path == null) return;

            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) {
                if ((FileObserver.ACCESS & event) != 0)        LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was accessed/read");     //data was read from a file
                if ((FileObserver.ATTRIB & event) != 0)        LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was changed (permissions, owner, timestamp)");   //Metadata (permissions, owner, timestamp) was changed explicitly
                if ((FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE & event) != 0) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, path + " was closed (no write)");          //someone has a file or directory open read-only, and closed it
                if ((FileObserver.DELETE_SELF & event) != 0)   LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + " was deleted");      //the monitored file or directory was deleted, monitoring effectively stops
                if ((FileObserver.MODIFY & event) != 0)        LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was modified");      //data was written to a file
                if ((FileObserver.MOVED_FROM & event) != 0)    LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was moved to somewhere");    //a file or subdirectory was moved from the monitored directory
                if ((FileObserver.MOVE_SELF & event) != 0)     LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, path + " was moved");                      //the monitored file or directory was moved; monitoring continues
                if ((FileObserver.OPEN & event) != 0)          LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, path + " was opened");                     //a file or directory was opened

                    //TODO: consider combine this one with one below
                    //a file was deleted from the monitored directory
                if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event) != 0) {
                    //for testing copy file
//                    FileUtils.copyFile(absolutePath + "/" + path);
                    LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was deleted");
                }
            }

            if ((FileObserver.CREATE & event) != 0) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was created");      //a new file or subdirectory was created under the monitored directory

                if ((new File(absolutePath + "/" + path)).isDirectory()) {
                    final SharedPreferences prefs = Application_Buddy_Tracker.getPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    initWatchers(getApplicationContext(), prefs.getString(getString(R.string.prefs_buddymessages_share_folder_root_key), ""));
                }
            }

            //a file or subdirectory was moved to the monitored directory
            if ((FileObserver.MOVED_TO & event) != 0) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "File was moved to " + absolutePath + "/" + path);

                if (path.endsWith(".json")) newMessage(absolutePath, path);     // Final action for new file in Bittorrent-Sync
            }

            //someone has a file or directory open for writing, and closed it
            if ((FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE & event) != 0) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " was written and closed (== changed)");

                if (path.endsWith(".json")) newMessage(absolutePath, path);     // Final action for new file in Bittorrent-Sync
            }
        }


        private void newMessage(String absolutePath, String path) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "Check if received message is new: " + path);

            if (BuddyMessage.addMessage(getApplicationContext(), absolutePath + "/" + path)) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (DEBUG_LEVEL > DEBUGLEVEL_NONE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "New message added to message-store: " + path);

                LeoCommunication.notifyNewMsg(getApplicationContext(), Application_Buddy_Tracker.RQ_NEW_MESSAGE_ARRIVED, Application_Buddy_Tracker.ID_NOTIFICATION_BUDDYTRACKER_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
            }
        }
    }


    private static boolean _isRunning = false;

    public static boolean isRunning() { return _isRunning; }


    /**
     * FileObservers that monior shared folders.
     * <p>Important: Keep (this) reference in order to not have the observers garbage collected!</p>
     */
    private final List<MyFileObserver> fileObservers = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_STANDARD) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand: Restarting Service (without intent)");
        } else {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_STANDARD) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand: Start service (with intent)");
        }


        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        final NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())                // Zeitpunkt der Notification
            .setContentTitle(context.getText(context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes))
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(de.leo.android.buddy_tracker.R.string.app_receiving_by_shared_folder))
            .setTicker(getResources().getString(de.leo.android.buddy_tracker.R.string.app_receiving_by_shared_folder));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)   nb.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) nb.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Activity_Main.class);
        intent1.putExtra(DISPLAY_TAB, Activity_Main.TABPOSITION_SHARE);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Application_Buddy_Tracker.RQ_SERVICE_RECEIVE_POSITIONS, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        nb.setContentIntent(pIntent);

        this.startForeground(Application_Buddy_Tracker.ID_NOTIFICATION_BUDDYTRACKER_RECEIVE, nb.build());

        final SharedPreferences prefs = Application_Buddy_Tracker.getPreferences(context);
        final String buddyMessages_Root = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.prefs_buddymessages_share_folder_root_key), "");

        if (!initWatchers(context, buddyMessages_Root)) {
            LeoLog.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand: initWatchers failed - stopping Service");
            stopSelf(startId);
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        _isRunning = true;

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand finished");

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        synchronized (fileObservers) {
            for (FileObserver fileObserver : fileObservers)
                fileObserver.stopWatching();
            fileObservers.clear();
        }

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_STANDARD) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "disconnect: Fileobservers and Service stopped");

        _isRunning = false;
        stopForeground(true);
    }


    private boolean initWatchers(Context context, String buddyMessages_Root) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_EXTENDED) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "initWatchers");

        if (buddyMessages_Root == null || buddyMessages_Root.length() == 0) return false;

        final File rootDir = new File(buddyMessages_Root);

        synchronized (fileObservers) {
            fileObservers.clear();

            initWatchers1(rootDir.getAbsolutePath());

            final Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_BUDDIES_URI, new String[]{COL_BUDDY_SHARED_FOLDER},
                    COL_BUDDY_ACTIVE + " != 0 AND " + COL_BUDDY_SHARED_FOLDER_RECEIVE + " != 0 AND " + COL_BUDDY_SHARED_FOLDER + " IS NOT NULL",
                    null,
                    null);
            assert c != null;
            while (c.moveToNext())
                initWatchers1(c.getString(0));
            c.close();
        }

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "initWatchers finished");

        return true;
    }


    private boolean initWatchers1(String rootpath) {
        if (rootpath == null) return true;

            // Watcher for the rootdir -> monitor add and remove of buddies
        final MyFileObserver fileObserver1 = new MyFileObserver(rootpath);
        fileObservers.add(fileObserver1);
        fileObserver1.startWatching();
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "initWatchers1: Watcher for root " + rootpath + " created");

        File dir1 = new File(rootpath);

        for (File f : dir1.listFiles())
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                MyFileObserver fileObserver = new MyFileObserver(f.getAbsolutePath());
                fileObservers.add(fileObserver);
                fileObserver.startWatching();

                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUGLEVEL_VERBOSE) LeoLog.i(LOG_TAG, "initWatchers1: Watcher for subdirectory " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " created");
            }

        return  true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using threads and AsyncTask, there are no guarantees about timing of execution.

Comment: A am aware of the properties of threads etc.
Please note that the task is started with minimum delay when the filewatcher-service is not active.
The 22s delay has to have a reason. Other than the started service (which is started 21 before) the device was mostly idle. So there is no reason that my AsyncTask is delayed for that long time.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) should be used for short running tasks.

   > `AsyncTask` is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. `AsyncTasks` should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as `Executor`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `FutureTask`.
2. By default your [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) runs on UI Thread

   > Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

Start your service in separate Thread or convert it to [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). If your `AsyncTask` takes longer time for execution of tasks, replace it with other alternatives as recommended in suggestion 1.

Comment: Quite a long time since I posted that ...
The Async-Task is used for a short running task.
The Service is running on the UI-Thread - yes. But it is used only to start some File-Watchers and has completed long ago.
The File-Watchers themselves are asynchroneous - so I don't expect them to be harmful on the UI-Thread. Otherwise that should have been mentioned in the documtentation.

My question was, why there is such a big delay until my AsycTask is started - I can not see anything that might be responsible for that delay.